# android studio: https self signed certificate not trusted

Tags: android-studio, ssl, openssl, ca

trying to access https://localhost:5000/ that has my own self signed certificate through android studio 
(with kotlin), and I keep getting the error: **java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.**

Ive made the certificate using openssl through a guide i found [**here**](https://kracekumar.com/post/54437887454/ssl-for-flask-local-development) using method 2

I have tried adding an network_security_config.xml file that looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">https://10.0.2.2:5000/</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/my_ca"/>
            <certificates src="user"/>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and I have made inside of res a folder called raw and put inside of it my_ca.pem, (which i converted from crt using `openssl x509 -in server.crt -out server.pem -outform PEM` and renamed to my_ca.pem)

I also tried adding that certificate on the android studio settings, or allowing all untrusted sites, the code to the html request is as simple as i found:

```
URL("https://10.0.2.2:5000/").readText()
```

, it is inside an AsyncTask class, but all the class does is this request

Im accessing 10.0.2.2 and not 127.0.0.1 because from what i understood, its the way to access the local mchine through te emulator, and the erver code is a very simple python-flask code that returns a simple string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out, altough i did enable self signed certificate on android studio, I didnt enable them on kotlin, so the error came from kotlin and not android studio, a quick copy-paste from [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032463/kotlin-connect-to-self-signed-https-server)

has solved it, altough I dont understand a thing from it, and if someone could send me a refrence to some sort of explantion or a tutorial for it that would be wonderful.